# Replacing line in file if string matches

Tags: shell

I have a file that contains the below line

```
define(`AbcBuild', `2012.05.04-1101')
```

which needs to change to

```
define(`AbcBuild', `latest')
```

I have tried with below command but it is not working

```
sed -i  's/^define(`AbcBuild.*/define(`AbcBuild\', `latest\')/' file
```

Is there any easy way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Grave or singlequote escaping is kind of tricky. You can use something like that:

```
sed -f 's/^define(`AbcBuild.*$/define(`AbcBuild'\'', `latest'\'')/g' file
```